# Multiple prompts in array with variable, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, prompt

```
var arr[2];
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = prompt() * 1;
}
```

But i was wondering you can do like var `arr = [x,y,z] = [1,2,3];` can you do a loop for "x, y, z" with a prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this by using the [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor and [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The [`Array#fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is necessary in order to let `map` iterate through the whole array:

```js
var [x, y, z] = Array(3).fill().map(prompt).map(Number)

console.log(x, y, z)
```

This approach uses the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for making it easyer

Comment: @StojanSpasic all those methods have links, just click on them.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an array with `prompt`s and assign it to variables:

```js
var prompts = [
  prompt('0', '0'),
  prompt('1', '1'),
  prompt('2', '2'),
];
var [x, y, z] = prompts;
console.log(x, y, z);
```

Comment: Neither of these actually do anything with the `prompt()`... FYI, I'm not the one that downvoted, I'm just making an observation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, what do you mean? What should we do with `prompt()`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, if you mean that i didn't pass any default content - the OP didn't say, that he needs it. But i have updated the answer with prompt's content

Comment: I meant you didn't assign it to anything... they're just a bunch of pointless prompts that don't actually store anything to memory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store variable references in an array, you could store the variables in an object, however:

```js
var x;
var y;
var z;
var arr = {
  x,
  y,
  z
};
for (key in arr) {
  arr[key] = prompt() * 1;
}
console.log(arr);
```